# Draw a diagram in latex 2

Tags: diagrams

I want to be like the output below. I hope that someone can help. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you get stuck when you tried the tikz-cd package manual?

Answer (score 7):

Where's the problem? For the LaTeX code see below the image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
Step 1: Arrange the nodes.

\begin{tikzcd}
  0 & X   & M   \\
  0 & X/A & M/A \\
    & N 
\end{tikzcd}

\bigskip
Step 2: Add the arrows.

\begin{tikzcd}
  0 \ar[r] & X  \ar[r]\ar[d] & M  \ar[d]\ar[ldd,dashed]\\
  0 \ar[r] & X/A\ar[r]\ar[d] & M/A\ar[ld,dashed]       \\
           & N 
\end{tikzcd}

\bigskip
Step 3: Add labels to the arrows.

\begin{tikzcd}
  0 \ar[r] & X  \ar[r,"j"]\ar[d,"p'"] & M  \ar[d,"p"]\ar[ldd,dashed,"\exists h'"] \\
  0 \ar[r] & X/A\ar[r]\ar[d,"f"]      & M/A\ar[ld,dashed,"\exists h"]             \\
           & N 
\end{tikzcd}

\bigskip
Step 4: Fine-tuning.

\begin{tikzcd}
  0 \ar[r] & X  \ar[r,"j"]\ar[d,"p'",swap] & M  \ar[d,"p"]\ar[ldd,dashed,"\exists h'",swap,pos=0.25]\\
  0 \ar[r] & X/A\ar[r]\ar[d,"f",swap]      & M/A\ar[ld,dashed,"\exists h"]                          \\
           & N 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Those are exact sequences, so the `O` should be `0`.

Comment: @egreg Ok, so may it be.

Comment: Sometimes i think a screenshot of the working code would be more suited as an answer. Leaves at least the typing as an effort to the OP.

Comment: @Johannes_B Well, the answer is not only meant for the OP but for all those that will stumble over it in the future. This motivates me to make the answer easy to use.