# Commutative diagram with curve connecting between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem with Tikz as follows: I want to draw a curve connecting the node `$H_q(X_1)$` and `$H_q(X_1,A)$`. I used the command `\draw[bend right,->]  (-2) to node [anchor=north]{$H_{n-1}(Id)$} (10)`; in the last line of my code below but the result is not good. The curve drawn is above letters as shown:

[image]

How can I make this curve bend more to the left? This is the code of my diagram:

```
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={midway}]
  \matrix[column sep={10em,between origins}, row sep={2.9em}] at (0,0) {
   \node(-14) {}; & \node (-13) {};&\node(-12) {};\\
  \node(-11){} ; & \node(-10) {$H_{q+1}(X,A)$};&\node(-9) {}; \\
 \node(-8) {$H_{q+1}(X_2,A)$}; & \node (-7) {};&\node(-6) {$H_{q+1}(X_1,A)$};\\
  \node(-5){} ; & \node(-4) {$H_q(A)$};&\node(-3) {}; \\
 \node(-2) {$H_q(X_1)$}; & \node (-1) {};&\node(0) {$H_q(X_2)$};\\
   \node(1){} ; & \node(2) {$H_q(X)$};&\node(3) {}; \\
 \node(4) {$H_q(X,X_2)$}; & \node (5) {};&\node(6) {$H_q(X,X_1)$};\\
     \node(7) {}; & \node (8) {$H_q(X,A)$};&\node(9) {};\\
     \node(10){$H_q(X_1,A)$} ; & \node(11) {};&\node(12) {$H_q(X_1,A)$}; \\
    \node(13) {}; & \node (14) {$H_{q-1}(A)$};&\node(15) {};\\
    \node(16){$H_{q-1}(X_2)$} ; & \node(17) {};&\node(18) {$H_{q-1}(X_1)$}; \\
    \node(19) {}; & \node (20) {$H_{q-1}(X)$};&\node(21) {};\\
    \node(22){} ; & \node(23) {};&\node(24) {}; \\
     };

      \draw[->] (-14) -- (-10) node[anchor=south]  {};
      \draw[->] (-13) -- (-10) node[anchor=south]  {};
      \draw[->] (-12) -- (-10) node[anchor=south]  {};

     \draw[->] (-4) -- (-6) node[anchor=north]  {$\partial_{(q+1)_1}^*$};
  \draw[->] (-4) -- (-8) node[anchor=north]  {$\partial_{(q+1)_2}^*$};
  \draw[->] (-6) -- (-10) node[anchor=south]  {$H_q(l_1)$};
  \draw[->] (-8) -- (-10) node[anchor=south]  {$H_q(l_2)$};

  \draw[<-] (-2) -- (-4) node[anchor=south]  {$H_q(m_1)$};
  \draw[<-] (0) -- (-4) node[anchor=south]  {$H_q(m_2)$};
  \draw[->] (-2) -- (2) node[anchor=north]  {$H_q(i_1)$};
  \draw[->][red] (0) -- (2) node[anchor=north]  {$H_q(i_2)$};


  \draw[->] (2) -- (4) node[anchor=south]  {$H_q(s_2)$};
  \draw[->] (2) -- (6) node[anchor=south]  {$H_q(s_1)$};
  \draw[<-] (4) -- (8) node[anchor=north] {$H_q(j_2)$};
  \draw[<-] (6) -- (8) node[anchor=north] {$H_q(j_1)$};

  \draw[<-] (8) -- (10) node[anchor=north]  {$H_q(l_1)$};
  \draw[<-] (8) -- (12) node[anchor=north]  {$H_q(l_2)$};
  \draw[->] (10) -- (14) node[anchor=north] {$\partial_{q_1}^*$};
  \draw[->] (12) -- (14) node[anchor=north] {$\partial_{q_2}^*$};

  \draw[->] (14) -- (16) node[anchor=south]  {$H_{q-1}(m_2)$};
  \draw[->] (14) -- (18) node[anchor=south]  {$H_{q-1}(m_1)$};
  \draw[->] (16) -- (20) node[anchor=north] {$H_{q-1}(i_2)$};
  \draw[->] (18) -- (20) node[anchor=north] {$H_{q-1}(i_1)$};

   \draw[<-][thick][green] (4) -- (10) node[anchor=east] {$H_q(k_1)$};
   \draw[<-] (6) -- (12) node[anchor=west] {$H_q(k_2)$};


    \draw[->] (-10) -- (-4) node[anchor=west]  {$\partial_{q+1}^*$};
   \draw[->] (-4) -- (2) node[anchor=west]  {$H_{q}(m)$};
    \draw[->] (2) -- (8) node[anchor=west]  {$H_{q}(n)$};
    \draw[->] (8) -- (14) node[anchor=west]  {$\partial_{q}^*$};
     \draw[->] (14) -- (20) node[anchor=west]  {$H_q(m)$};

      \draw[->] (20) -- (22) node[anchor=west]  {};
        \draw[->] (20) -- (23) node[anchor=west]  {};
          \draw[->] (20) -- (24) node[anchor=west]  {};


      \draw[bend right=75,->]  (-2) to node [anchor=east]{$H_{q}(n_1)$} (10);   
      \draw[bend right=75,->]  (4) to node [anchor=east]{$\partial_{q_2}^*$} (16);   

       \draw[bend left=75,->]  (0) to node [anchor=west]{$\partial_{q_2}^*$} (12);   
       \draw[bend left=75,->]  (6) to node [anchor=west]{$\partial_{q_2}^*$} (18);   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Thank you in advance.

Edit: How can we avoid the case that for example, `$H_q(s_2)$` is overwritten the line connecting `$H_q(X)$` and `$H_q(X,X_2)$`?

PS: I solved the bending problem.

Second edit: I use Tikz-Cd as recommended by Egreg. The code is:

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
& {H_q(A)}  \arrow[dl,swap,"H_q(m_1)"] \arrow[dd,"H_q(m)"] \arrow[dr,"H_q(m_2)"] \\
H_q(X_1) \arrow[dr,swap,"H_q(i_1)"]
  \arrow[dddd,bend right=50,swap,"H_{n-1}(\mathit{Id})"] &&
  H_q(X_2) \arrow[dddd,bend left=50,"H_{n-1}(\mathit{Id})"]  \arrow[red,dl,"H_q(i_2)"] \\
& H_q(X) \arrow[dl,swap,"H_q(s_1)"] \arrow[dd,"H_q(n)"] \arrow[dr,"H_q(s_2)"] \\
H_q(X,X_2)\arrow[dddd,bend right=50,swap,"H_{n-1}(\mathit{Id})"]  && H_q(X,X_1)\arrow[dddd,bend left=50,"H_{n-1}(\mathit{Id})"]  \\
& H_q(X,A) \arrow[ul,"H_q(j_2)"] \arrow[ur,swap,"H_q(j_1)"] \arrow[dd,"\partial_q^*"] \\
H_q(X_1,A) \arrow[uu,"H_q(k_1)"] \arrow[ur,swap,"H_q(l_1)"] \arrow[dr,swap,"\partial^*_{q_1}"] &&
  H_q(X_1,A) \arrow[ul,"H_q(l_2)"] \arrow[uu,swap,"H_q(k_2)"] \arrow[dl,"\partial^*_{q_2}"] \\
& H_{q-1}(A) \arrow[dl,swap,"H_{q-1}(m_2)"] \arrow[dd,"H_{q-1}(m)"] \arrow[dr,"H_{q-1}(m_1)"] \\
H_{q-1}(X_2) \arrow[dr,swap,"H_{q-1}(i_1)"]
  &&
  H_{q-1}(X_1) \arrow[red,dl,"H_{q-1}(i_2)"] \\
& H_{q-1}(X)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

The result is:

[image]

The problem now is that I can't draw the tail and the head exactly like my original picture. It always shows error? How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
& {} \arrow[dl] \arrow[dd,swap,"n"] \arrow[dr] \\
H_q(X_1) \arrow[dr,swap,"H_q(i_1)"]
  \arrow[dddd,bend right=50,swap,"H_{n-1}(\mathit{Id})"] &&
  H_q(X_2) \arrow[red,dl,"H_q(i_2)"] \\
& H_q(X) \arrow[dl,swap,"H_q(s_1)"] \arrow[dd,swap,"n"] \arrow[dr,"H_q(s_2)"] \\
H_q(X,X_2) && H_q(X,X_1) \\
& H_q(X,A) \arrow[ul,"H_q(j_2)"] \arrow[ur,swap,"H_q(j_1)"] \arrow[dd,"\partial"] \\
H_q(X_1,A) \arrow[uu,"H_q(k_1)"] \arrow[ur,swap,"H_q(l_1)"] \arrow[dr,swap,"\partial^*_q"] &&
  H_q(X_1,A) \arrow[ul,"H_q(l_2)"] \arrow[uu,swap,"H_q(k_2)"] \arrow[dl,"\partial^*_q"] \\
& {}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Egreg, Thank you so much. But I am not familiar with this package, I added a new picture and new code into my post. Could you fix the overwriting problem for me?

Comment: What does it mean by dl, dr, uu?

Comment: @AnKhuongDoan No, sorry. I think you can easily build on my code for completing the diagram.

Comment: @AnKhuongDoan My recommendation: Familiarize yourself with tikz-cd, it is [really easy to use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356862/110998). `dl` means down-left, `dr` means down-right, `uu` means up-up.

Comment: I am trying to farmilizer with this :D. What about dddd?

Comment: @AnKhuongDoan Go down by four rows

Comment: `dl` means **d**own-**l**eft, `dr` means **d**own-**r**ight, `uu` means **u**p-**u**p, so `dddd` means ....?

Comment: Hi @egreg, I try to use tikz-cd, to draw it, but i can not handle to draw exactly like the tail and the head of my original pictur. Can you take a look on my new code and my new picture?

Comment: I can handle it now :D.